# Symfony 2 OutOfBoundsException: The index "1" is not in the range [0, 0]

Tags: symfony

I would like redirect User for changing password form after authorization succes and I get this error:
OutOfBoundsException: The index "1" is not in the range [0, 0].

```
    namespace Infogold\KonsultantBundle\Service;

    use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\TokenInterface;
    use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
    use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authentication\AuthenticationSuccessHandlerInterface;
    use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
    use Symfony\Component\Routing\RouterInterface;

    /**
     * Custom authentication success handler
     */
    class AuthenticationSuccessHandler implements AuthenticationSuccessHandlerInterface
    {

        protected $router;

       /**
        * Constructor
        * @param RouterInterface   $router
        */
       public function __construct(RouterInterface $router)
       {
          $this->router = $router;

       }

function onAuthenticationSuccess(Request $request, TokenInterface $token)
   {
.
.
.
```

My service

```
parameters:
    security.authentication.success_handler.class: Infogold\KonsultantBundle\Service\AuthenticationSuccessHandler

services:
    security.authentication.success_handler:
        class: %security.authentication.success_handler.class%       
        arguments:  ['@router']
```

and Security with two firewalls, first is my firewalls second is from FOSuserBundle:

```
    firewalls:
              konsultant_area:
                pattern:    ^/konsultant
                context: my_context1
                anonymous:    true  
                form_login:  
                    provider:                       administrators    
                    use_forward:                    true 
                    login_path:                     /konsultant/login
                    check_path:                     /konsultant/login_check               
                    post_only:                      true 
                    always_use_default_target_path: true  
                    default_target_path:            /konsultant/klient/indywidualni               
                    use_referer:                    false
                    success_handler:                security.authentication.success_handler

                    failure_path:                   /konsultant/login  
                    failure_forward:                false  

                    username_parameter:             _username  
                    password_parameter:             _password 

                logout: true

              main:  
                pattern: ^/ 
                context: my_context2
                .
                .
                .
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my probblem. For sombody who occur this error:
I replaced dots on underscore in

```
success_handler:               security.authentication.success_handler
success_handler:               security_authentication_success_handler
```

and in services:

```
parameters:
    security_authentication_success_handler.class: Infogold\KonsultantBundle\Service\AuthenticationSuccessHandler

services:
    security_authentication_success_handler:
        class: %security_authentication_success_handler.class%
        public: false
        arguments:  ['@router']
```

Now is everything alright.